# Footnote is not working in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}

%draw
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered]
        \foreach \x in {-8, -7.4, -6.8, -6.2}
        \foreach \y in {1.8, 1.2, ..., -2.4}
            \draw[thick] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+0.5,\y+0.5);

        \foreach \x in {7, 6.4, 5.8}
        \foreach \y in {0, -0.6, -1.2, -1.8}
            \draw[blue, thick] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+0.5,\y+0.5);

        %\draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -0.05) rectangle (-5.65, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-6.85, -0.05) -- (-5.65, -0.05);
        \draw[red, thick] (-5.65, -0.05) -- (-5.65, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-5.65, -1.85) -- (-7.45, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -1.85) -- (-7.45, -0.65);
        \draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -0.65) -- (-6.85, -0.65);
        \draw[red, thick] (-6.85, -0.65) -- (-6.85, -0.05);
        \draw[red, thick] (-8.05, 2.35) rectangle (-5.65, 1.75);
        \node (sprints) {Sprints};

        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (175:5em) node[above left=1em and 0.5em] {Stand-up Meeting\footnote{Daily}} arc (175:95:5em);
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (85:5em) arc (85:5:5em) node[above right=1em and 0.5em] {Development\footnote{Sprint burn down}};
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (265:5em) arc (265:185:5em) node[below left=1em and 0.1em] {Retrospective\footnote{After each Sprint}};
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (355:5em) node[below right=1em and 0.5em] {Planning} arc (355:275:5em);

        \draw[->,-latex,line width=0.1em] +(-20em,-5em) -- +(-2em,-5em);
        \draw[->,-latex,line width=0.1em] +(2em,-5em) -- +(20em,-5em);

        \node (start) [below left=4.5em and 10em of sprints] {Spring Backlog};
        \node (end) [below right=4.5em and 10em of sprints] {Workable Release};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
    \caption{Working flow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But no footnote output is showing. How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this might work. Note the footnote numbering between brackets after each `\footnotetext`

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}

%draw
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}%        <--- added too

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered]
        \foreach \x in {-8, -7.4, -6.8, -6.2}
        \foreach \y in {1.8, 1.2, ..., -2.4}
            \draw[thick] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+0.5,\y+0.5);

        \foreach \x in {7, 6.4, 5.8}
        \foreach \y in {0, -0.6, -1.2, -1.8}
            \draw[blue, thick] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+0.5,\y+0.5);

        %\draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -0.05) rectangle (-5.65, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-6.85, -0.05) -- (-5.65, -0.05);
        \draw[red, thick] (-5.65, -0.05) -- (-5.65, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-5.65, -1.85) -- (-7.45, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -1.85) -- (-7.45, -0.65);
        \draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -0.65) -- (-6.85, -0.65);
        \draw[red, thick] (-6.85, -0.65) -- (-6.85, -0.05);
        \draw[red, thick] (-8.05, 2.35) rectangle (-5.65, 1.75);
        \node (sprints) {Sprints};

        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (175:5em) node[above left=1em and 0.5em] {Stand-up Meeting\footnotemark} arc (175:95:5em);
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (85:5em) arc (85:5:5em) node[above right=1em and 0.5em] {Development\footnotemark};
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (265:5em) arc (265:185:5em) node[below left=1em and 0.1em] {Retrospective\footnotemark};
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (355:5em) node[below right=1em and 0.5em] {Planning} arc (355:275:5em);

        \draw[->,-latex,line width=0.1em] +(-20em,-5em) -- +(-2em,-5em);
        \draw[->,-latex,line width=0.1em] +(2em,-5em) -- +(20em,-5em);

        \node (start) [below left=4.5em and 10em of sprints] {Spring Backlog};
        \node (end) [below right=4.5em and 10em of sprints] {Workable Release};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
    \caption{Working flow}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext[1]{Daily}
\footnotetext[2]{Sprint burn down}
\footnotetext[3]{After each Sprint}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since there are many footnotes you have to specify the counter, because once you issue the three `\footnotemark`s, the footnote counter is set to three, and the `\footnotetext`s will all be numbered three. If you compile your code, the marks are numbered correctly, but the footnotes not.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I appreciate you noticed it. I have edit my code and now numbering works. Thank you for the edit as well.

Comment: @Cragfelt may I know why `footnote` can't use directly? must be replaced by `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`

Comment: @HowChen I am sorry. I do not have an answer to that. But it sounds a good question to be asked in another post. I suggest you to make it.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace each `\footnote` by a pair of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`. Since there are multiple footnotes, you can automate the process duplicating the `footnote` counter:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}

%draw
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered]
        \foreach \x in {-8, -7.4, -6.8, -6.2}
        \foreach \y in {1.8, 1.2, ..., -2.4}
            \draw[thick] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+0.5,\y+0.5);

        \foreach \x in {7, 6.4, 5.8}
        \foreach \y in {0, -0.6, -1.2, -1.8}
            \draw[blue, thick] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+0.5,\y+0.5);

        %\draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -0.05) rectangle (-5.65, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-6.85, -0.05) -- (-5.65, -0.05);
        \draw[red, thick] (-5.65, -0.05) -- (-5.65, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-5.65, -1.85) -- (-7.45, -1.85);
        \draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -1.85) -- (-7.45, -0.65);
        \draw[red, thick] (-7.45, -0.65) -- (-6.85, -0.65);
        \draw[red, thick] (-6.85, -0.65) -- (-6.85, -0.05);
        \draw[red, thick] (-8.05, 2.35) rectangle (-5.65, 1.75);
        \node (sprints) {Sprints};

        \newcounter{tfn}
        \stepcounter{footnote}
        \setcounter{tfn}{\value{footnote}}
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (175:5em) node[above left=1em and 0.5em] {Stand-up Meeting\footnotemark[\value{tfn}]\stepcounter{tfn}} arc (175:95:5em);
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (85:5em) arc (85:5:5em) node[above right=1em and 0.5em] {Development\footnotemark[\value{tfn}]\stepcounter{tfn}};
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (265:5em) arc (265:185:5em) node[below left=1em and 0.1em] {Retrospective\footnotemark[\value{tfn}]\stepcounter{tfn}};
        \draw[->,latex-,line width=0.1em] (355:5em) node[below right=1em and 0.5em] {Planning} arc (355:275:5em);

        \draw[->,-latex,line width=0.1em] +(-20em,-5em) -- +(-2em,-5em);
        \draw[->,-latex,line width=0.1em] +(2em,-5em) -- +(20em,-5em);

        \node (start) [below left=4.5em and 10em of sprints] {Spring Backlog};
        \node (end) [below right=4.5em and 10em of sprints] {Workable Release};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
    \caption{Working flow}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]{Daily}\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]{Sprint burn down}\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]{After each Sprint}\stepcounter{footnote}

\end{document}
```

Each additional footnote you may need you put `\footnotemark[\value{tfn}]\stepcounter{tfn}` on the due location and `\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]{<Text of the footnote>}\stepcounter{footnote}` after the `\end{figure}`.

Comment: mau I know why `footnote` can't use directly? must be replaced by `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`

Comment: @HowChen Sorry for the late reply. That is because LaTeX typesets the footnote when the page is being shipped out, after the `\end{tikzpicture}`. When you issue a `\footnote` command, the content is stored until it is time to typeset the footnote (proof of this is that when you have two footnotes, the second will be below the first). But when you use the `\footnote` inside a `tikzpicture`, the contents are, for some reason that I don't know, lost. That is why you have to use a pair of `footnote`-`mark`-`text`, that will save the text _after_ the `tikpicture` is over.